# Magjack to TPS2378 connection

Tags: ethernet, poe, networking, 8p8c

I'm designing a PoE shield for an ESP32, but am having some trouble figuring out the CT connections for the TPS2378. In their schematic, they have some rectifiers connected to the CT pin of each ethernet pair:

[image]

However, my magjack has all CT pins connected together, am i missing something, or is that unusable for this application? If so, whats such a magjack good for?

[image]

If the above is unusable for this application, is this any better, at least for Mode A PoE? If so, how do i connect this to the TPS2378? Do i simply skip D6, D7, D12 and D13, and just connect P4 and P5 to D4, D5, D10 and D11 in the TPS2378 schematic?

[image]

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with PoE (hence why this isn't an answer), but I believe neither of the mag jack schematics you show are usable for it. They are both suitable for ethernet communications, just not for PoE.

Answer (score 1):

Your magjacks are unsuitable for PoE because there is no access to center taps of individual pairs. In fact there is no pins at all to access the cable side CTs.

What it is good for is everything with Ethernet that does not require PoE.

Comment: Isn't the last one good for Mode A? It has two CTs, one for TX (1&2) and one for RX (3&6)

Comment: @MaciejSwic No it doesn't have two CTs, not on the cable side, and you have not got any pins to access the cable side CTs.

Comment: P4 & P5? Or is that not it?

Comment: @MaciejSwic P4 and P5 are the board-side CTs, which are useless for PoE.

Comment: @Hearth What are they there for then? Just trying to understand..

Comment: @MaciejSwic Probably for termination? I'm not an expert on ethernet, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: @MaciejSwic They are for powering the IC side of the coil, when IC uses current mode driver. Or keeping common mode balance with a capacitor when IC uses voltage mode drive. So no, not used for termination really at all, termination is at the data pins.

Comment: @Hearth Are you absolutely sure about that? I mean no offense, but i looked up the jack used by the Arduino Ethernet Shield 2 which supports PoE, and judging by what you wrote, it looks like its even less suitable for PoE as it only has one CT and its also board-side? Cant paste an image here but here is the datasheet https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Wiznet-RB1125BAG1A/C910370

Comment: @MaciejSwic Are you sure this is the jack used in the ethernet shield 2? Because it doesn't seem to match the pinouts on the shield's [schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Ethernet-Shield2-V2-sch.pdf), which for some reason don't specify a part number. In particular, it doesn't seem to have R7, R8, R9, or R10 pins, all of which are used for the PoE support.

Comment: @MaciejSwic That magjack you linked also has no available connections to cable side CT. There is no way it can be used for PoE.

Comment: @Hearth Yes - but no. I opened in Eagle and got RB1-125BHQ1A, pasted that into google and then copied it again from the results for another search and for some reason it became RB1-125BAG1A... So my bad. I now see the RB1-125BHQ1A is wired differently. Thanks.

Comment: How about this? 4,5 & 7,8 are going to the bridge rectifiers, thats Mode B, correct? But the bridge rectifiers also connect to the board-side 1,3 & 5,6? Looks like Mode A but its board-side? https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/853893653282976/HR861153C%20.pdf According to HanRuns website it says "Support different PoE (IEEE802.3af, IEEE802.3at, IEEE802.3bt, etc.)"